# Dart - error in object instantiation and method invocation

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I have a class named `Track`, which holds the title, author and other basic details of a music track, and also a class named `Library` which is supposed to work with the `Track` class and manage all the tracks, add new ones, remove etc, now the problem is when I'm trying to invoke the method `addTrack` of an object of the class `Library`, I'm getting the error "missing function parameters" when I am already passing in a track object to the method.

I am stuck on this, I tried googling about classes and came across a few examples but in those too the method invocation is not working, giving the same error, I tried running the code in dartpad, and also in the flutter SDK, both don't seem to work.

Here is the code,

```
class Track {
  var author, duration, image, title;

  Track({this.title, this.author, this.duration, this.image});
}

class Library {
    List<Track> tracks = [];

    void addTrack(Track t) {
      tracks.add(t);
    }
}

final music =  Library();

Track t = new Track( title: "hi");

music.addTrack(t);
```

Comment: Is your posted the exact code you tried in DartPad?

Comment: I tried it on dartpad and it worked!

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yes

Comment: error
The name 'music' is already defined - line 19
error
A function body must be provided - line 19
error
Expected a method, getter, setter or operator declaration - line 19
error
Functions must have an explicit list of parameters - line 19
error
A function body must be provided - line 19

I'm getting these errors, while pasting the exact same code on dartpad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a main method somewhere. I wrapped the bottom three lines with main and your code works fine.

```
void main() {
  final music = Library();
  Track t = new Track( title: "hi");
  music.addTrack(t);
}
```

Comment: Oh. I made such a silly mistake... thanks for the help.

Comment: It's no problem. Everyone makes silly mistakes every now and then.

Comment: @AdarshHegde Accept my answer if it helped you out!